# how to exclude spring method security for system call?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

When a user requests create item, permissions must be checked,
so the code was written as follows.

```java
@PreAuthorize("@permissionEvaluator.canWrite()")
public Result createItem(InstallInfo installInfo) {
  ....
}
```

However, there are cases where the same method is called by the system.
For example, new items can be created through spring scheduler.
when i call the method in scheduler,
spring occur authentication error.
`org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`

This error can be resolved in the following two ways.

- separate method
- set admin security context forcibly

but i want more common way to bypass the security method.
Is there another, more common-sense approach?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/mikaelhg/52e5a4d9d72f6b5411af) helps

Comment: That is why there is **Run As** support in Spring Security. You can create a separate system user and when the system invokes this method have it run as the system (which would have the correct credentials). That would be the correct way IMHO.